# "message": "HTTP 400 Bad Request", "exception": "jakarta.ws.rs.WebApplicationException"

Tags: jax-rs

When i use jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest as a context param in rest API getting below exception,
"message": "HTTP 400 Bad Request",
"exception": "jakarta.ws.rs.WebApplicationException".

Thanks

I have tried adding different gradle dependencies.